# How to delete user's post after he deleted his account? - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

*I'm guessing something should be added to the post model.*
After I cancel my account I still find the posts but with nil user. How can I remove user's post with the account?

Answer (score 4):

In your `User` model, you need to modify the below association by adding the `dependent` option:

```rb
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

Reference: [Rails `ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods` documentation, “Deleting from associations”](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Deleting+from+associations)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like this in your User model. It will essentially cascade the delete upon deleting a user.

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: Answered first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like before your delete action is performed you can find the related posts of user and delete them first. Then after you can delete the user .